# multiple nested foreign key relations in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fetch an object that traverses 2 models with reverse foreign key relations. I have been able to fetch the object of the first model (ipv4address), but am unable to fetch the object(s) that are linked to that object through reverse foreign keys.
I'm fairly new to django, so I might be approaching this wrong to begin with. Any suggestions are more then welcome.

I passed all peer objects to the template as such:

```
    def view_ix(request, ix):
            peers = Peer.objects.filter(exchange=ix).order_by('asn')
            return render_to_response('view_ix.html', {
                                                    'peers': peers,
                                                    'exchange' : ix,
                                                    'exchanges' : exchanges.list(),
                                            }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Models:

```
    class Peer(models.Model):
            exchange                = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            organisation            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
            contact                 = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
            asn                     = models.IntegerField()
            def __unicode__(self):
                    return  unicode(self.asn) + '\t' + unicode(self.organisation)

    class IPv4Address(models.Model):
            peer                    = models.ForeignKey(Peer)
            ip                      = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
            def __unicode__(self):
                    return  unicode(self.peer) + '\t' + unicode(self.ip)

    class Router(models.Model):
            name            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            fqdn            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            snmpport        = models.IntegerField()
            snmpcommunity   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            def __unicode__(self):
                    return  unicode(self.name)

    class PeerStatus(models.Model):
            router          = models.ForeignKey(Router)
            ipv4address     = models.ForeignKey(IPv4Address)
            state           = models.IntegerField()
```

Template:

```
    {% for peer in peers %}
            {% for ipv4 in peer.ipv4address_set.all %}
                ipv4: {{ ipv4.ip }}<br>
                {% for state in ipv4.peerstatus_set.all %}
                    state: {{ state.state }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I just realized I did not fill up my database again (specifically the PeerStatus table) after debugging time and time again... Now after filling it again, I realize my code actually works... bit of a blunder ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually works as designed... The issue was in the (lack of) database content.